# Rolling Oncall Distribution List with Microsoft Exchange

Tags: exchange, configuration, scripting, distribution-lists

I'm trying to set up an "oncall" user/email for Microsoft Exchange (ex: `oncall@mybiz.org`), with the idea being that whoever on my team is currently "oncall" will be added to the list. Then, when they are no longer on-call, they will be removed from the list, and the next on-call person added.

We have 12 people on my team, with very rigorous on-call schedules. Wondering if Exchange supports this type of behavior, or how I might be able to script something together if the functionality doesn't come out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible to create but does not come with a solution "out of the box". Best approach (imo) would  be to create a dynamic distribution group based on an AD attribute (there are a number of custom attributes you could use for this) and a powershell script to set and remove the attribute.

Depending on how your on call is recorded you could use a CSV file with a date check to see if the current date is within the set range of the CSV.